# Init method for core data entity not available

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am on xcode 6.1 and developing for iOS 8.1. I have simple project called *CoreDataTest* where I play around with core data.

Model:

```
import CoreData

class Licence: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
}
```

and

[image]

Now I want to create a licence object. This is what I need prior to creating the object:

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Licence", inManagedObjectContext: context)
```

The problem is that xcode does not provide the correct constructor for the entity. When I start typing:

```
var newLicence = Licence(..
```

I get no auto completion like in this example:

[image]

I just get the NSManagedObject() as auto completion. Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: For Xcode 6.1.1, the auto completion doesn't show up, but the init method (using entity and managed object context) could still be called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it by reading the docs for [**NSManagedObject**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-223939) :)

> It is important that a managed object is properly configured for use
>   with Core Data. If you instantiate a managed object directly, you must
>   call the designated initializer
>   (initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)

So in my class I implemented:

```
override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
}
```

and now it works.

Comment: This must be new in a recent version of xcode. I've seen it done without having to do this. (possibly in an earlier version)

Comment: Note that it also says: _You are discouraged from overriding this method—you should instead override awakeFromInsert and/or awakeFromFetch (if there is logic common to these methods, it should be factored into a third method which is invoked from both). If you do perform custom initialization in this method, you may cause problems with undo and redo operations._