# Is something wrong with Xcode? I am constantly missing important parameters

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift

Recently I have been experimenting with Coredata by making a couple of applications locally. I noticed whenever I make an object and save things onto core data, I do not seem to be able to view the complete parameters provided by the framework when attempting to create an object. I don't know what the terminalogy is for this step, but I was attempting this:

```
 let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Feeditem", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

let feedItem = FeedItem( <--- PROBLEM RIGHT HERE
```

Instead of getting this to pop up:

```
(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
```

I get this: [image]

Why is this so?

Here is a project in which the same thing was happening: https://github.com/Somnibyte/Errands

Comment: There is no FeedItem in the project you uploaded. You should make your question match your example.

Comment: Matt, I was trying to do another experiment. The point is that both of them were behaving like this. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly for me on the project you uploaded:

[image]

Comment: Do you recommend that I delete Xcode and then re-download it? This is so bizarre. I knew I was doing everything right!

Comment: I am using Xcode 6 on Yosemite by the way. If we both have the same configurations, than this is quite an odd bug.

Comment: Hmm. I'm still on Mavericks. Could that really be the difference? ... Have you restarted the computer? I find that this is sometimes necessary in order to slap Xcode across the head. Also, consider doing a cleaning as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994

Comment: Yeah, I did quite a lot of cleaning various time, but with no luck. I found another person with the same problem. Over here: . I tried a solution found on the thread where you could modify the entity class. My entities class is currently "ErrandModel", I changed it to "Errands.ErrandModel". I added the projects name before the period. And it seem to print out the core data test, BUT with an error on top:

Comment: 2014-10-31 12:28:27.530 Errands[2716:39234] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'Errands.ErrandModel' for entity 'ErrandModel'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
<NSManagedObject: 0x7ffb4a636170> (entity: ErrandModel; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://A3F69FBA-6870-48DB-ABB7-0ECE2ECC78FC/ErrandModel/p2> ; data: {
    info = Test;
    item = Test;
    quantity = Test;
})

Comment: Here is the thread by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599574/cant-instantiate-subclass-of-nsmanagedobject?rq=1

Comment: Okay. I've seen a lot of stuff that looks related. I think what we're seeing here is a Swift bug having to do with inherited initializers.

Comment: Thank you for the help matt, I got it to work. Just fetched the data, it seems that it was there, but I couldn't print the data being saved. Nonetheless, it works fine now.